# Input_from Conv_1D signal data

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

This is my signal [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWTE1.png)

The length of each sample data is = 64.
The sum of train data is =49572

```
length=len(x_train)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(length,64)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(3),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(3),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(3),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(3),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(29, activation='softmax')
 ])
```

I want to make a CNN model for signal data. So, I use `Conv1d`.
How to know the input_shape from my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the keras [`Conv1D`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv1D) documentation:

> When using this layer as the first layer in a model, provide an
> input_shape argument (tuple of integers or None, e.g. (10, 128) for
> sequences of 10 vectors of 128-dimensional vectors, or (None, 128) for
> variable-length sequences of 128-dimensional vectors.

From your image, it seems like your data is simple 1-dimensional hat means `length` should equal to `1` in your case.

Think of the `length` dimension as the color channel of an image in the 2D convolution case. Black-white images have only a single color dimension, therefore `width x height x 1`, whereas RGB images have 3 color channels, hence `width x height x 3`.
Similar, if you work with time series and 1D convolutions you may have more then one signal, e.g. temperature + atmospheric pressure + humidity measured throughout the day for each minute. Then your signal would be of shape `1440 x 3`